# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEVNULL'

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

```
from nltk.parse.corenlp import CoreNLPServer
server = CoreNLPServer()
server.start()
```

When I run the above code, I'm getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 30, in <module>
    server.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/parse/corenlp.py", line 130, in start
    stderr=stderr,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 112, in java
    subprocess_output_dict = {'pipe': subprocess.PIPE, 'stdout': subprocess.STDOUT, 'devnull': subprocess.DEVNULL}
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEVNULL'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`subprocess.devnull`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL) is new in Python 3.3.

Make sure you use a version of `nltk` which stil supports Python 2.7.  From [their changelog](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/ChangeLog):

```
Version 3.5 2019-10-16
* drop support for Python 2
```